# Jquery on new Window objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use jQuery on a new Window javascript object?

Example:

```
win = new Window('mywindow','width= 400', 'height=400');

win.getContent().innerHTML = xmlFindNodeContent(XmlHttp.responseXML, "windowHtml");

jQuery(win).ready(function(){
  do jQuery stuff on the new window here??
});
```

Is something like this possible?

NB: new Window() function takes some parameters before it works properly. Something like this:

window.open('mywindow','width=400,height=200')

Comment: What is `new Window()` supposed to do? It doesn't do anything in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code i wrote in topic myself and it works great!

Thumbs up for jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

I think is better to insert the jquery.min.js on the new windows and there do the $(function(){// jquery stuff });

Comment: No this is exactly what i do not wanna do, because then html parsed to the new window is auto generated from serverside.